# theorems of partial differentiation

Tags: partial-derivative

[image]

Can we simply hold $x$ or $z$ constant for all of the equation ? (not only for one partial differentiation)

furthermore, if we hold $x$ constant so that $dx= 0$ like what he did in the last equation, we will have [image]

so:

[image]

Comment: $x$ is only held constant while taking the derivative $\partial y/\partial z$.

Comment: he substituted dx= 0 in equation 5.13, so it is a constant for all of the situation